# finding MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for iid Beta($\theta$,1) RV's

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to find the MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$ for iid $Beta(\theta,1)$ RV's.

If I want to find the MLE of $\theta$, the normal calculation for computing the MLE gives $\hat{\theta}=-\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^n\log X_i}$. For finding MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$, should I do change of variables in the very first step of calculation? Thank you.

Comment: I don't rhink so. Just take the reciprocal at the end.

Comment: You can do it at the beginning or the end.  Note that for $x>0$, you have $f(x)=\frac1x$ bijective $\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$, strictly monotonic, and differentiable, so it will work either way